# Running `pip` gives 'command not found' after successful Python homebrew install

Tags: python, terminal, pip, homebrew

To preface, I am very bad with the terminal, please be patient with me.

when I run `pip` I get:
    `zsh: command not found: pip`

I have installed Python 2.7.11 with brew, which should allow pip to work
When I run `echo $PATH` I get

```
/usr/local/sbin /Users/Nicolas/.composer/vendor/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

I notice that /usr/local/bin/ is in there, which I understand is where brew executables are linked to

when I run `which -a python` I get

```
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

So-- two Python installs. I'm guessing one is the native OSX one and one is the homebrew install.
When I run `which python` I get

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

So this is the python that gets run when python is called, right?
When I run `ls -l $(which python)` I get

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Nicolas  admin  34 Feb  3 14:26 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/python
```

I think this is where the problem is; I notice that there is a /python/2.7.11/libexec folder...

I have also tried `brew unlink python && brew link python` to no avail

when I try `brew list python | grep pip` I get a very long list of results

This is probably the most important one

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/libexec/pip/pip/__init__.py
```

I don't know how to proceed from here... I think it has to do with pip being in `python/2.7.11/libexec` instead of `python/2.7.11/bin`

I am not familiar with most of this stuff; my understanding of terminal is very limited. I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any and all help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do yourself a favour, download get-pip.py https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and install it with python get-pip.py

Comment: I downloaded that to my desktop, cd'd there and ran python get-pip.py... I get this output: 

Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-19.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (472kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 475kB 960kB/s
Installing collected packages: setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-19.7 

now when I run 'pip' I still get the same error (command not found)

Comment: what does `which -a pip` output?

Comment: what about `/usr/bin/python -m pip`  and  `/usr/local/bin/python -m pip`

Comment: I don't understand -- are those commands? When I attempt to run the first one, I get  Usage:
  /usr/bin/python -m pip <command> [options]

Followed by instructions...

It doesn't appear to accept any parameters to the command. When I run /usr/bin/python -m pip -v   

It gives me the same output as with /usr/bin/python -m pip

Comment: then it means pip is working, you could run  `/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install requests` and it would work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102517/discussion-between-naguirre-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 28):

I ran into this problem myself on OS X. In my case, I finally did a listing of /usr/local/bin, and found that I had links from `pip2`, `pip2.7`, `pip3`, and `pip3.6`. What I lacked was a link from just `pip`. I don't know if this is just part of a new standard, or if I was missing something that would select one of the two, or if having both Python 2 and Python 3 installed meant that I didn't get a simple `pip` command. Either way, running `brew doctor` didn't reveal or solve any issues.

In this case, just running `pip3` or `pip2` (instead of `pip`) seemed to do the trick for me. In my case, I ran `pip3` and everything installed and ran as expected.

Comment: quick fix based on this answer from @Steve - did `cd /usr/local/bin`, found the entry  for `pip3`, noticed `pip` was missing, (inside that directory) simply copied the file to `pip` and everything worked! Thanks for the lead!

`cp pip3 pip`

Comment: Create a symlink instead

Answer (score 9):

### My Background

I had this same problem, and I think it may have arisen after upgrading to OSX 10.11 (El Capitan).  When trying to run pip, I got `-bash: pip: command not found`  I also tried `python -m pip` which did not work either (`no module found`).  Trying to unlink and relink python through Homebrew did not work.

### The Fix

I was able to fix the problem by completely uninstalling and reinstalling python via Homebrew.

```
brew uninstall python && brew install python
```

If you want to remove older versions of python too, use

```
brew uninstall --force python && brew install python
```

None of my existing pip installs were affected, and are all still listed when I run `pip freeze`.  After the reinstall, the binary is now symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/pip`, which did not exist before.  Strangely, the actual binary in `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/pip` did not exist before the reinstall either.

Comment: If brew complains about dependencies, you might have to do `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force python && brew install python`. It's ok to ignore dependencies, because you're reinstalling right away. You might also have to relink: `brew unlink python && brew link python`

Answer (score 3):

Uninstalling/reinstalling did not fix it for me but `brew` provided this info:

> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
> `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been
> installed into   /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin

So adding `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin` to my path fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those who search for a solution also nowadays, with python 3 - brew installs them both, but and as you noticed, that's how you run python:

```
$ python3
```

That's the same story with pip:

```
$ pip3
```

If it bothers you (it bothers me) - you can alias those two to your prefered form:

```
$ alias python=python3
$ alias pip=pip3
```