# Pip is not found for brewed Python (3)

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I brewed python, but could not find pip. There is pip source code in python bin path, but no executable files.

I read a similar article [Pip packages not found - Brewed Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624757/pip-packages-not-found-brewed-python) that is helpless for me.

When brewing python, I also got the following error

> Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step The
>   formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local Permission denied
>   @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks Error: Permission denied @
>   dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Try running with sudo, otherwise you might want to run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`
(as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/7732946))

Else, you can try uninstalling and reinstalling again (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35615175/10763533))

Otherwise, you can always install pip separately with `easy_install pip`

Comment: `easy_install pip` will install pip for python2 that came with mac, since `easy_install` is also belong to python2. I will have a look at the suggestion.